# Woocommerce Removing "Additional information" Name On Checkout Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In my Wordpress Woocommerce site I have removed all of the shipping and billing details so the customer only has to enter their first, last and email. I'm selling vertical products, I don't want or need all those details.  What I'm still seeing is **Additional Information** name  is still showing up.

**Your Information**

First Name *

Last Name *

Email Address *

Confirm Email Address *

**Additional Information**

When I look at the html from the page I see:

```
</p></div>
</p></div>
<div class="col-2">
<div class="woocommerce-shipping-fields">
<h3>Additional Information</h3>
</p></div>  
</p></div>
</p></div>
```

It's some how plugged in so I can't just delete it.  If I can please give insight how to find what file it might be in.

This is the code I've included in my child theme to remove all billing and shipping info:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);

return $fields;
}
```

Thanks in advance for helpful advice

Answer (score 40):

try to add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false');
```

Comment: where you get this code? It works for me but I want to learn it how to find this info? =)

Comment: hi,
you can see woocommerce use that filters on `woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php` line `62`

Answer (score 4):

To remove the whole Additional information section use:-

```
add_filter('woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false');
```

And If you just want to remove the Additional information text:-

```
function wc_order_review_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

  if(is_checkout()){
    switch ($translated_text) {
      case 'Billing details' :
        $translated_text = __( 'Billing Info', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
      case 'Additional information':
        $translated_text = __('New Field Name', 'woocommerce');
        break;
     case 'Your order':
        $translated_text = __('My Order', 'woocommerce');
        break;
     case 'Product':
        $translated_text = __('Your Product', 'woocommerce');
        break;
    }
  }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_order_review_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Additional Information** title is located in file:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php
```

However i recommend you to create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and make your customizations there. Adding the filter that @qutek recommends also works.

If you want to get rid of the 2 columns style that the checkout comes with, you should customize the div with the "customer_details" id located in file:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php
```